# Expression Blend reload file shortcut

Tags: expression-blend

Is there any way to reload a file open in expression blend, from using a keyboard shortcut or any other shortcut? Currently, while in expression blend, I just close it from the "x" button, and then re-open it, but its tedious. Is there any other alternative?

I find myself needing to close a file and re-open it to refresh the design view. Because if I edit for example some data templates, the changes I made in the code part of the split view, are not reflected immediately in the design part of the split view.

Hence, I need a way to make blend reload the file.

**EDIT:** One way to overcome this limitation is to make the content inside your data-template a user control and edit that in Blend.

But my initial question still stands.

Comment: I've never seen Blend not display changes immediately (I also rarely edit XAML directly in Blend). Could you post some specifics and a step-by-step for recreating this problem?

Comment: You're right, most of the time it does display changes automatically (e.g. for a simple listbox with a datatemplate). But I'm using a telerik grid with datatemplate selectors, which gets populated in expression blend from a design-time view-model which is set with d:DataContext. And in this case the grid (filled with design time data) doesn't refresh automatically when I edit a data-template. That's why I have to extract the datatemplates into separate user controls, and design them there. I still think a reload file shortcut would be useful in some of these "more complex" scenarios.

Comment: Blend is notoriously bad about reloading resource dictionaries that are modified externally.  I think that's what you're running into and why your work around works.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding a project? ctr-shift-b